# javax.websocket client simple example

Tags: java, websocket

Can someone please provide me very simple example of websocket client using `javax.websocket`?

I want to connect to websocket (ws://socket.example.com:1234), send message (add channel) and listen to messages. All messages (sent & listened) are in JSON format.

And btw is this library the best for simple websocket communication?

Answer (score 146, accepted):

I've found a great example using `javax.websocket` here:

http://www.programmingforliving.com/2013/08/jsr-356-java-api-for-websocket-client-api.html

Here the code based on the example linked above:

**`TestApp.java`**:

```
package testapp;

import java.net.URI;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;

public class TestApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            // open websocket
            final WebsocketClientEndpoint clientEndPoint = new WebsocketClientEndpoint(new URI("wss://real.okcoin.cn:10440/websocket/okcoinapi"));

            // add listener
            clientEndPoint.addMessageHandler(new WebsocketClientEndpoint.MessageHandler() {
                public void handleMessage(String message) {
                    System.out.println(message);
                }
            });

            // send message to websocket
            clientEndPoint.sendMessage("{'event':'addChannel','channel':'ok_btccny_ticker'}");

            // wait 5 seconds for messages from websocket
            Thread.sleep(5000);

        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            System.err.println("InterruptedException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        } catch (URISyntaxException ex) {
            System.err.println("URISyntaxException exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

**`WebsocketClientEndpoint.java`**:

```
package testapp;

import java.net.URI;
import javax.websocket.ClientEndpoint;
import javax.websocket.CloseReason;
import javax.websocket.ContainerProvider;
import javax.websocket.OnClose;
import javax.websocket.OnMessage;
import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.WebSocketContainer;

/**
 * ChatServer Client
 *
 * @author Jiji_Sasidharan
 */
@ClientEndpoint
public class WebsocketClientEndpoint {

    Session userSession = null;
    private MessageHandler messageHandler;

    public WebsocketClientEndpoint(URI endpointURI) {
        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            container.connectToServer(this, endpointURI);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Callback hook for Connection open events.
     *
     * @param userSession the userSession which is opened.
     */
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session userSession) {
        System.out.println("opening websocket");
        this.userSession = userSession;
    }

    /**
     * Callback hook for Connection close events.
     *
     * @param userSession the userSession which is getting closed.
     * @param reason the reason for connection close
     */
    @OnClose
    public void onClose(Session userSession, CloseReason reason) {
        System.out.println("closing websocket");
        this.userSession = null;
    }

    /**
     * Callback hook for Message Events. This method will be invoked when a client send a message.
     *
     * @param message The text message
     */
    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        if (this.messageHandler != null) {
            this.messageHandler.handleMessage(message);
        }
    }

   @OnMessage
   public void onMessage(ByteBuffer bytes) {
        System.out.println("Handle byte buffer");
    }

    /**
     * register message handler
     *
     * @param msgHandler
     */
    public void addMessageHandler(MessageHandler msgHandler) {
        this.messageHandler = msgHandler;
    }

    /**
     * Send a message.
     *
     * @param message
     */
    public void sendMessage(String message) {
        this.userSession.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
    }

    /**
     * Message handler.
     *
     * @author Jiji_Sasidharan
     */
    public static interface MessageHandler {

        public void handleMessage(String message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, how to make this code work if the websocketServer is sending a continuous stream of messages and websocketClient needs to consume the messages one by one?
I get the error "The decoded text message was too big for the output buffer and the endpoint does not support partial messages" after running the code for about a minute

Comment: Make sure to maven-import org.java-websocket.

Comment: This code fails with the error: Could not find an implementation class.

Comment: @deathgaze javax.websocket api is only the specification don't have full implementation you may need to take the jar file tyrus-standalone-client-1.9.jar and try the same example that should solve your problem. i tested with my example and it is working fine.

hope this will help you.

Comment: @Martin How can I send a message on Open.
Example : I need to send '{"type":"subscribe","symbol":"AAPL"}' on open the websocket to subscribe.

Comment: for those who is getting  error "Could not find an implementation class." should also include tyrus-standalone-client-1.9.jar while building . you can download it from [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/glassfish/tyrus/bundles/tyrus-standalone-client/1.9/)

Answer (score 50):

TooTallNate has a simple client side https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket

Just add the java_websocket.jar in the dist folder into your project.

```
 import org.java_websocket.client.WebSocketClient;
 import org.java_websocket.drafts.Draft_10;
 import org.java_websocket.handshake.ServerHandshake;
 import org.json.JSONException;
 import org.json.JSONObject;

  WebSocketClient mWs = new WebSocketClient( new URI( "ws://socket.example.com:1234" ), new Draft_10() )
{
                    @Override
                    public void onMessage( String message ) {
                     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(message);
                     String channel = obj.getString("channel");
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onOpen( ServerHandshake handshake ) {
                        System.out.println( "opened connection" );
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onClose( int code, String reason, boolean remote ) {
                        System.out.println( "closed connection" );
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError( Exception ex ) {
                        ex.printStackTrace();
                    }

                };
 //open websocket
 mWs.connect();
 JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
 obj.put("event", "addChannel");
 obj.put("channel", "ok_btccny_ticker");
 String message = obj.toString();
 //send message
 mWs.send(message);
```

// and to close websocket

```
 mWs.close();
```

Comment: Worked in Windows 7, windows 8 and OS X mountain lion using eclipse, server was Ubuntu.

Comment: why would you choose this library instead of javax ones?

Comment: cause it's obviously simpler

Comment: which changes are needed to support wss protocol (secured ws)?

Comment: Now the Draft_6455 is used in the code instead of Draft_10

Comment: The client is connecting to the websocket server for only 1minute. Is there a possiblity to connect to the socket forever to receive a continuous stream of messages?

Comment: Great library, but it has problems with wss. The project has several open issues, and the developer comments he does not have time anymore.

Comment: Regarding disconnect after 1 minute, see [https://github.com/TooTallNate/Java-WebSocket/issues/560] for a possible reason/solution.

Comment: This lib only works in UTF-8 also, something to keep in mind.

Answer (score 24):

Have a look at this Java EE 7 examples from Arun Gupta.

I forked it [on github](https://github.com/koekiebox/javaee7-samples/tree/master/websocket/javase-client/src/main/java/org/javaee7/websocket/javase/client).

**Main**

```
/**
 * @author Arun Gupta
 */
public class Client {

    final static CountDownLatch messageLatch = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
            String uri = "ws://echo.websocket.org:80/";
            System.out.println("Connecting to " + uri);
            container.connectToServer(MyClientEndpoint.class, URI.create(uri));
            messageLatch.await(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        } catch (DeploymentException | InterruptedException | IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(Client.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

**ClientEndpoint**

```
/**
 * @author Arun Gupta
 */
@ClientEndpoint
public class MyClientEndpoint {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connected to endpoint: " + session.getBasicRemote());
        try {
            String name = "Duke";
            System.out.println("Sending message to endpoint: " + name);
            session.getBasicRemote().sendText(name);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(MyClientEndpoint.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void processMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println("Received message in client: " + message);
        Client.messageLatch.countDown();
    }

    @OnError
    public void processError(Throwable t) {
        t.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: You should mention that it requires the websocket dependency shipped seperately

Answer (score 5):

Use this library org.java_websocket

First thing you should import that library in build.gradle

```
repositories {
 mavenCentral()
 }
```

then add the implementation in dependency{}

```
implementation "org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.3.0"
```

Then you can use this code

In your activity declare object for Websocketclient like

```
private WebSocketClient mWebSocketClient;
```

then add this method for callback

```
 private void ConnectToWebSocket() {
URI uri;
try {
    uri = new URI("ws://your web socket url");
} catch (URISyntaxException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    return;
}

mWebSocketClient = new WebSocketClient(uri) {
    @Override
    public void onOpen(ServerHandshake serverHandshake) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Opened");
        mWebSocketClient.send("Hello from " + Build.MANUFACTURER + " " + Build.MODEL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMessage(String s) {
        final String message = s;
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.edittext_chatbox);
                textView.setText(textView.getText() + "\n" + message);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onClose(int i, String s, boolean b) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Closed " + s);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(Exception e) {
        Log.i("Websocket", "Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
};
mWebSocketClient.connect();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I have Spring 4.2 in my project and many SockJS Stomp implementations usually work well with Spring Boot implementations. [This implementation from Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/websockets-spring) worked(for me without changing from Spring 4.2 to 5). After Using the dependencies mentioned in his blog, it still gave me ClassNotFoundError. I added the below dependency to fix it.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I added an implemenation that worked for Spring MVC. why the downvote?

Comment: Spring was not questioned for. Other java-dependent client applications (e.g. android app's) cannot make use of this

Comment: @MojioMS But what is the probability that someone will open this question for SpringMVC and I will offer that answer? Isn't it better the OP ignores this answer because he has Java but not spring mvc? For those who have a websocket issue and have spring, this contribution could be useful.

Comment: Well, I've made that - lets call it 'mistake' - too. I didn't vote down your answer but just wanted to give an explanation. It might be useful to add some kind of 'Spring Framework solution'-title to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is such a solution from - com.neovisionary.ws.client.Web socket - https://github.com/TakahikoKawasaki/nv-websocket-client

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URI;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocket;
import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketAdapter;
import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketException;
import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFactory;
import com.neovisionaries.ws.client.WebSocketFrame;

public class WssM {

    public static List<String> ListMessage = new ArrayList<>();
    public static boolean WebSocketLog = true;
    public static final String WssURL = "wss://site.com/api/sport_tree_ws/v1";
    public static final String WebsocketMessage = "{\"type\": \"subscribe_state\", \"subscribe_state\": {\"uid\": \"-1\"}}";

    

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, WebSocketException {
        WebSocket socket = connect(WssURL);
        BufferedReader in = getInput();
        socket.sendText(WebsocketMessage);
        String text;
        try {
            while ((text = in.readLine()) != null) {
                if (text.equals("exit")) break;
                if (!socket.isOpen()) {
                    System.out.println("Socket is closed. Trying to reconnect...");
                    socket.recreate().connect();
                    System.out.println("Reconnected!");
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (socket.isOpen()) {
                System.out.println("Disconnecting connection to server!");
                socket.disconnect(); //Close the WebSocket.
            }
        }
    }
    private static WebSocket connect(String Host) throws IOException, WebSocketException {
        WebSocketFactory wsFactory = new WebSocketFactory().setConnectionTimeout(55000);
        WebSocket socket = wsFactory.createSocket(URI.create(Host)).addProtocol("json");//.addHeader("Sec-WebSocket-Protocol", "json")
        //WebSocket socket = wsFactory.createSocket(URI.create(HOST + "?Authorization=" + DUMMY_JWT_TOKEN));
        socket.addListener(new WebSocketAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onSendingHandshake(WebSocket websocket, String requestLine, List<String[]> headers) {
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.println(requestLine);
                for (String[] header : headers) { //Print the header, "{name}: {value}"
                    if (WebSocketLog) System.out.format("%s: %s\n", header[0], header[1]);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onConnected(WebSocket websocket, Map<String, List<String>> headers) {
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.println("Success! WebSocket - Connected!");
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextMessage(WebSocket websocket, String text) {
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.printf("MessageToClient: %s%n", text); ListMessage.add(text);
            }
            @Override
            public void onDisconnected(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketFrame serverCloseFrame, WebSocketFrame clientCloseFrame, boolean closedByServer) {
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.println("Disconnecting...");
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.printf(" Opcode: %d%n", serverCloseFrame.getOpcode());
            }
            @Override
            public void onPongFrame(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketFrame frame) {
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.printf("Received some pong..!! Payload text: %s%n", frame.getPayloadText());
                System.out.printf(" Opcode: %d%n", frame.getOpcode());
            }
            @Override
            public void onPingFrame(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketFrame frame) {
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.printf("I have been pinged by server at %s%n", LocalDateTime.now());
                websocket.sendPong("Ponging from client");
            }
            @Override
            public void onTextFrame(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketFrame frame) {
                if (WebSocketLog) System.out.printf("onTextFrame - %s%n", LocalDateTime.now());
                websocket.sendPong("onTextFrame from client");
            }
            @Override
            public void onError(WebSocket websocket, WebSocketException cause) {
                System.out.printf("I have received exception %s%n", cause.getMessage());
            }
        }).connect();
        return socket;
    }

    private static BufferedReader getInput() {
        return new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    }
}
```