# Is possible to test signalR messages with SoapUI?

Tags: signalr, integration-testing, soapui

In my team we are using SoapUi to test the public REST API, but we have some signals reported by SignalR that we can't test.

A long search session in Google doesn't provide me information...

There is any way to add signalR checks as test steps in SoapUI?

Answer (score 1):

I'm read about [signalr](/questions/tagged/signalr) just right now, however seems that it's based on *WebSockets*, if it's your case unfortunately nowadays *SOAPUI* (version 5.2.1) doesn't support it by default.

You can try with a custom code in a *Groovy testStep* to hit your webSocket, there are some samples on how to [implement it using *Java*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example). Note that you can use the Java code directly in a *Groovy testStep*.

Alternatively as @SiKing comment it's also possible to do it using [this plugin](http://github.com/pbielicki/soapui-websocket-transport).

Hope it helps,

Comment: Thanks for your answer. SignalR can use WebSockets but can use another protocols based on what the clients supports (http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr). I'm thinking in create a process in .NET that can handle SignalR notifications and exposes a REST API that can be called from Soap UI.

Comment: I do not know about SignalR, but for websocket support in SoapUI, see https://github.com/pbielicki/soapui-websocket-transport

Comment: Yes, it is possible to request websocket using SoapUI as @SiKing rightly mentioned. I tried websocket sometime ago.