# WebSocket in Java throws javax.websocket.DeploymentException

Tags: java, websocket, tyrus

So I'm trying to create a WebSocket client in Java. I used the code from the first answer
[javax.websocket client simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example)

I imported the tyrus-standalone-client 1.9 and org.java-websocket Java-Websocket 1.3.0 with Maven.
When I try to run this this error occurs:
Caused by: javax.websocket.DeploymentException
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:376) ~[project.jar:?]
at org.default.project.connection.WebsocketClientEndpoint.(WebsocketClientEndpoint.java:21) ~[project.jar:?]

How can I solve this error?