# Websokcet use asynchronous communication?

Tags: java, asynchronous, websocket, communication

I must write a JAVA standalone websocket client. I know that webscoket is a duplex communication protocol, but I don't know how does it exactly work. This communication is asynchronus? (like a JMS queue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since Websockets use an underlying TCP-Connection, all communication should be done asynchronously. This is, however, an implementation detail of your code. If you want to block your code to wait for a reply, that's up to you (though not recommended).

Websockets for Java were specified in [JSR 356](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=356), so you can use them out-of-the-box in your application server. If you don't have an application server, you can use a standalone implementation like [Tyrus](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/tyrus) instead.

See [javax.websocket client simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example) for some code samples.