# Can I have a websocket connection client in a server? i.e a server subscribing to another server sending events

Tags: java, websocket

I am trying to come up with a solution that requires subscribing to websocket in a 3rd party server.

The thing is I need to listen to this in the server-side, not on client side. So somehow I need to keep this connection alive in my server (java) and listen to the websocket messages, which would then trigger something else.

I am a bit lost on how to achieve that and best patterns as apparently this is not really common.

Do you have suggestions on how should this be done?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [javax.websocket client simple example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26452903/javax-websocket-client-simple-example)